# remote control without taking over screen on Windows

Tags: remote-desktop, remote

Is there any remote desktop software for Windows that can access a computer, but not showing your session on the computer of the host and vice versa?

So for example:

Someone at the hostcomputer logs in as user A. And you login as user B at the same time. The person on the hostcomputer only sees session A and you the one who uses the remote desktop only sees session B. Like a kind of dualscreen configuration, but with the second screen taken by the remote desktop user.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Windows Terminal Services server package. You can't do it with the basic Windows desktop OS as far as I know.

Comment: Only for Windows server OS and special license is needed.

Answer (score 0):

[BO2K](http://www.bo2k.com/index2.shtml) with the [BoPeep](http://www.bo2k.com/software/bo2k11.html) plugin can do this, plus, it's free! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another round about way would be to login as another user, using the switch user option in windows. Then in that session run a virtual machine which is left running in the background and can be connected to as a separate ip address.
Then switch back out to the regular user leaving the virtual machine running as the other user.

It isn't ideal, because restarting will kill the background session, and requires perhaps a few more resources, but if everyone knows this is going on with the machine, it will work.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible  to remove limitation on concurrent connections by Terminal Services (RDP) by patching termserv.dll by using tool like [Universal Terminal Server Patch](http://www.deep-bg.net/?c=p&l=2&d=99). Don't know how much legal it is.

Comment: -1: It isn't legal.